# Как напечатать таблицу в с++?

Tags: c++, математика

Дано:
2
0
4 2
3 3
6 4 2
6 6 6
8 6 4 2
9 9 9 9
6 строк чётных и 2 строки нечётных.Блока 4.
Нужно на экране напечатать данную выше таблицу.
Вот мой код:

```
//напечатать таблицу
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

 int main() 
 {
     const int N = 4; //число блоков
     for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {//блоки
         for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) //нечетные строки
             cout << 1 + i << " ";
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) //четные строки
         cout << 1 - j << " ";
         cout << endl;
        
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Помогите исправить,при этом коде выводит в некоторых местах отрицательные числа.
Вот так должна выглядеть таблица:[image: Таблица]

Comment: Несколько раз перечитал ваш вопрос, но так и не понял, что дано и что нужно сделать. Простите)

Comment: Нужно напечатать числа данные в столбик.
То есть 2 первая строка,0 вторая 42-третья,33-четвёртая,642-пятая,666-шестая,8642-седьмая,9999-восьмая @wololo

Comment: Юрий в вопросе просто приведите дополнительно как должна выглядеть таблица по тем цифрам что вы привели - действительно, очень непонятно даже с объяснением

Comment: @Zhihar подредактировал

Comment: Юрий :(, ну все равно не понятно :(((( вы перечитайте, что у вас написано, даже с рисунком непонятно что нужно - это кстати одна из основных причин ошибок в алгоритмах - неправильное или неполное понимание задачи, реально не по русским написано и из объяснения не понятно ничего :( вы можете добавить словесное описание поподробнее

Comment: @Zhihar,в самом задании просто написано напечатать таблицу и дана последовательность чисел по строкам.

Answer (score 1):

уф, я кажется поседел пытаясь понять, что требуется, но кажется понял

вот что требуется сделать изложенное русским языком:

есть массив чисел, надо вывести последовательно числа в столбец блоками по 2 строки, при этом кол-во чисел в стоках каждого последующего блока больше на 1 чем у предыдущего!!!

Если это так, то в приведённом автором коде вообще не видно где эти числа (в описании есть, в коде нет), в коде перебираются лишь позиции, т.е. приведённый код не соответствует задаче

По идее должно так:

```
int arr[] = {2, 0, 4, 2, 3, 3, 6, 4, 2, 6, 6, 6, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6,};
int size = 21;

int pos = 0;

while (pos < size) {
    // вывести 2 строки 
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
        // вывести строку из row_size символов начиная с позиции pos
        for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
            if (pos < size)
                std::cout << arr[pos + i] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

        pos += row_size;
    }

    // увеличить размер строки
    row_size ++;
}
```

Comment: можно и так но в задании не написано использовать ли массив или нет.

Comment: @Юрий, тогда обращение к массиву можно легко заменить `std::cin >> n` - получением значения от пользователя или любым другим способом сформировать число, все остальное останется неизменным и позволит сформировать именно такой вид таблицы как вы привели на картинке

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо,cпасибо)Я уже сам дописал программу:

```
// напечатать таблицу
int main(){
 const int N = 4; //число блоков
     for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) 
     {//блоки
        for (int j = i; j; j--)
            cout << j*2 << " ";
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = i; j; j--) //четные строки
            cout << (i-1)*3 << " ";
        cout << endl;
     }
    }
```